# ClickOnce Deployment Error: Application improperly formatted... (website install)

Tags: deployment, visual-studio-2013, web, clickonce

I'm trying to deploy a program with ClickOnce. It works fine if I try the "install from CD" Version. If I try to deploy it in the "Install from a website" Version I get following Error if I try to run it:

> Cannot continue. The application is improperly formatted. Contact the
>   application vendor for assistance.

The detailed Error is:

```
PLATFORM VERSION INFO
    Windows             : 6.1.7601.65536 (Win32NT)
    Common Language Runtime     : 4.0.30319.18444
    System.Deployment.dll       : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    clr.dll             : 4.0.30319.18444 built by: FX451RTMGDR
    dfdll.dll           : 4.0.30319.34244 built by: FX452RTMGDR
    dfshim.dll          : 4.0.41209.0 (Main.041209-0000)

SOURCES
    Deployment url          : https://mywebsite.com/HBAPackageConfig.application

ERROR SUMMARY
    Below is a summary of the errors, details of these errors are listed later in the log.
    * Activation of https://mywebsite.com/HBAPackageConfig.application resulted in exception. Following failure messages were detected:
        + Exception reading manifest from https://mywebsite.com/HBAPackageConfig.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        + For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION FAILURE SUMMARY
    No transaction error was detected.

WARNINGS
    There were no warnings during this operation.

OPERATION PROGRESS STATUS
    * [2/5/2015 2:13:50 PM] : Activation of https://mywebsite.com/HBAPackageConfig.application has started.

ERROR DETAILS
    Following errors were detected during this operation.
    * [2/5/2015 2:13:51 PM] System.Deployment.Application.InvalidDeploymentException (ManifestParse)
        - Exception reading manifest from https://mywebsite.com/HBAPackageConfig.application: the manifest may not be valid or the file could not be opened.
        - Source: System.Deployment
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestDirectBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options, ServerInformation& serverInformation)
            at System.Deployment.Application.DownloadManager.DownloadDeploymentManifestBypass(SubscriptionStore subStore, Uri& sourceUri, TempFile& tempFile, SubscriptionState& subState, IDownloadNotification notification, DownloadOptions options)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.PerformDeploymentActivation(Uri activationUri, Boolean isShortcut, String textualSubId, String deploymentProviderUrlFromExtension, BrowserSettings browserSettings, String& errorPageUrl)
            at System.Deployment.Application.ApplicationActivator.ActivateDeploymentWorker(Object state)
        --- Inner Exception ---
        System.Xml.XmlException
        - For security reasons DTD is prohibited in this XML document. To enable DTD processing set the DtdProcessing property on XmlReaderSettings to Parse and pass the settings into XmlReader.Create method.
        - Source: System.Xml
        - Stack trace:
            at System.Xml.XmlCharCheckingReader.Read()
            at System.Xml.XsdValidatingReader.Read()
            at System.Deployment.Application.ManifestReader.FromDocument(String localPath, ManifestType manifestType, Uri sourceUri)

COMPONENT STORE TRANSACTION DETAILS
    No transaction information is available.
```

I tried to sign the application in Visual Studio but I still get this Error.
Has anybody a solution for my why this is not working? I tried in Chrome and IE.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to allow access to the Install folder. ClickOnce opens a new connection to the Install folder. So, even if you have access to the folder the new connection cannot access the components, for example the manifest.

In the example below, and just for brevity, open access is granted to MyInstallPath:

```
  <runtime>
    <location path="MyInstallPath">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="*" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    </location>
  </runtime>
```